# Create an image inside table cell using the image name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have a table that has cells that show chair.jpg sofa.gif etc... I am trying to replace the text with an image src using the following code

```
var isImgUrl= /.*?\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)/ig;
var txt=document.getElementById('comment');
txt.innerHTML=txt.innerHTML.replace(isImgUrl,'<img src="http://www.MYURL.COM/uploads_enquiry/$&"/> ');
```

However, I keep getting broken images because it is adding the "20%" to the image src - for example, it would show "20%Chair.jpg". How can I prevent this so it just adds the file name and removes the "20%"?

Answer (score 0):

may you mean `%20`, if that's true then just use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).